# How is the longbibliography option used in revtex?

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I would like my bibliography to display article titles. The documentation says to use the `longbibliography` option, but it won't compile, so obviously I am doing something wrong.

My doc looks like this:

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn,10pt,aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
...bla bla bla
\bibliography{rextextext}

\end{document}
```

Changing `\bibliography` to `\longbibliography` fails. Am I putting this in the wrong place?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`longbibliography` is an option to the class:

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn,10pt,aps,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
...bla bla bla
\bibliography{rextextext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note: if you want the ``longbibliography`` option to work, then you *need* to let the REVTeX class automatically choose the bibliography style by *not* including a ``\bibliographystyle{}`` command in your document, exactly as shown in egreg's example.  This is not made clear in the manual.