# Applying `longbibliography` option without using `\documentclass{revtex4-1}`

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex

I am using the revtex4-1 file `apsrmp4-1.bst` for my bibliography style, but am not using `\documentclass[...]{revtex4-1}` for the class option. That is, my document is something like

```
\documentclass[...]{puthesis}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{apsrmp4-1}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

This works fine as is, but I would like to use the `longbibliography` option of `apsrmp4-1` to display the titles of all references. The REVTeX documentation (and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28715/how-is-the-longbibliography-option-used-in-revtex)) suggests the `longbibliography` option should be put in `\documentclass[longbibliography,...]{revtex4-1}`, but this does not work for me because I'm not using the `revtex4-1` class. 
Any suggestions for where the option can be specified?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `longbibliography` option works by writing some commands to a `.bib` file that is read by `bibtex`.  In a standard `revtex4-1` document the name of this file is `XXXNotes.bib` where `XXX.tex` is the name of your tex file.

For a different documentclass you can get titles to appear by adding

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}
```

to the top of your own bibliography file and adding `\nocite{apsrev41Control}` to your `.tex` file.  To switch titles off, write `title=""` instead in the second line.

[image: Sample output]

`.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{art}

\nocite{apsrev41Control}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}

@Article{art,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title is here},
  journal =      {Jour.},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   2,
  number =   1,
  pages =    {1--23}
}
```

If you want to avoid modifying your own `.bib` file, create a new `.bib` file, say `mycontrol.bib` with the above two lines and pass it to `bibtex` by adding it as an argument to the `\bibliography` command, e.g.

```
 \bibliography{mycontrol,mymainbibfile}
```

You can get some explanation of the other options by looking in a `.bbl` generated by a `revtex4-1` document which includes comments such as

```
%Control: key (0)
%Control: author (0) dotless jnrlst
%Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
%Control: production of article title (0) allowed
%Control: page (1) range
%Control: year (0) verbatim
%Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
```

Comment: Thanks! However, bizarrely, this only works for me if I use `\nocite{*}` (which I'd rather not have to do as I have a rather large .bib file). Also, the XXXNotes.bib file is not being created. I tried creating this manually (and adding the `@CONTROL{...}` statements (which were there in a real REVTeX example I had), but it didn't seem as though LaTeX could recognize this.

Comment: Yes, I trashed all auxiliary files, and removed the .bbl file each time. It seems as though it isn't recognizing the two `@CONTROL` statements at the start of the bib file (unless I use `\nocite{*}`), since if I change other aspects (e.g., author or year), it doesn't recognize this either. In the console after running bibtex it says `Control: production of article title (-1) disabled`.

Comment: Made it work! Added `\nocite{apsrev41Control}` rather than `\nocite{*}`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed, I have just rechecked this and this `\nocite` command is necessary. I have updated the text of my answer.