# Long bibliography options of BibTeX in RevTeX using LyX

Tags: bibtex, lyx, revtex

I'd like to let titles appearing in a bibliography generated by BibTeX on LyX running RevTeX and using the style `apsrev4-1.bst`. In principle there is a `longbibliography` option one can use in the call of the package `revtex4-1` which directly allows for this option, but it doesn't work on my distribution. Does anyone encounter the same problem ? Is there a way to fix this ?

I'm running LyX 2.1.4 on a MacOS computer with MacTeX inside. I've tried to play around the Bilbiography options of LyX, using NatBib, default, and Jurabib but it does nothing it seems (except Jurabib, which is absolutely not working).

Answer (score 2):

So, as explained in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28715/32124), one should not put a `bibliographystyle` entry if one wants `BibTeX` to compute correctly the `longbibliography` option.

Then a working example of the long bibliography option is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aps,rmp,12pt,tightenlines,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\cite{AuthorXXXX}

%\FAULTY LINE
%\bibliographystyle{apsrmp4-1}
%\TO BE REMOVED

\bibliography{some-bibliography}
\end{document}
```

In `LyX`, one should put no entry in the field `style` in the box `BibTeX generated bibliography` (let this field blank and click on OK is not a problem for LyX).